# Error in Import txt file from Google Drive to Google colab

Tags: python, import, txt

I am new to Python and google colab, I am trying to import a txt.file containing 0's and 1's into google collab from my Google Drive, however I am receiving this error code 'No columns to parse from file'.

Could anyone help me understand what is wrong with the code that caused this error? Thank you

`from google.colab import drive`

`drive.mount('/content/drive')`

`file = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/Graph2021.txt', 'r').read()`

[image: Sample Txt file]

[image: Error Code]

Comment: Are you using `read_csv` or `csv anywhere?

Comment: @kinshukdua, no i am not, when i used pd.read_csv it prompts error 'No columns to parse from file

Comment: That was my question, so the error only comes when you're trying to use `pd.read_csv`, right?

Comment: @kinshukdua I am abit confused, I tried both methods using open (picked from other poster in the forum) & pd.read.csv, both methods can't work. I did not tried combining them together

Comment: Can you put the full code here?

Comment: And please show not only the code but the complete traceback of the error, starting with the word *traceback* and ending with the error you reported. Then it would be less necessary for us to repeatedly ask you to clarify.

Comment: @BoarGules you can find the error code now, sorry for the inconvenience, will take note of that in the future

Comment: @srdg the 3 lines above are my full code